# How to query Firestore based on a date condition

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I have a "tasks" collection containing several documents (each is a "task"). Each task has a "dueDate" field.

I would like to query tasks due today onwards.

I know I could get today's date from the device, but that is not safe, as user can change the date from Settings and then be able to query by any date. I do not want user to view tasks due in the past.

What I am looking for is a way to generate today's date on the server, then use it as a filter for the query.

Something like:

```
let todayMidnight = <get server timestamp, then reset time components to 0 (to start at midnight)>

databaseReference.collection("tasks").order(by: "date").whereField(field: "date", isGreaterThan: todayMidnight).getDocuments()
```

Edit: I know I could use Cloud Functions to do this query but I guess I lose the ability to create listeners on my application that would auto-update data in the app once it changes.

Comment: If you don't want someone to be able to read a document, forcing the query won't really cut off read access (they could still find the document anyway).  Consider using a security rule instead to cut off access.

Comment: To rephrase, I guess you are suggesting to use security rules to deny read access if the date supplied in the query does not match today's date generated on the server. This could work but is a bit of a hack. I know Firestore has FieldValue.serverTimestamp but it only works for write operations. If something like it exists for read operations that would be ideal.

Comment: You can use the server date in the rule to cut off access.  Please check the docs.  I think you just compare to `now` or something like that.

Comment: I created a http request cloud function to retrieve the time from the server.

Comment: @TroelsLenda that could work, but if the user is offline, you probably fall back to the device date, which the user could manipulate to retrieve data from the local cache. Ideally, Firestore should build in the ability to compare dates in the database to the server date, conceptually similar to FieldValue.serverTimestamp used in write operations.

Comment: Okay, so what about letting a cloud function be responsible for setting a property on your document. Something like, "due_today_onwards": true

You want the cloud function to trigger timed at just after midnight, and whenever a task document is altered.

Then simple query the collection with your boolean property.

Comment: Good idea. Will give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Comment: I am still to implement it but Im pretty sure it should work nicely!